# How to delete a windows registry in matlab?

Tags: matlab, registry

I created a windows registry key and value via matlab code. But i don't know how to delete/remove the registry key.

How can i delete the registry key throught matlab?

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: the ideia is that i want to use the existence of the key. If the key exists then perform operation on my program. if not then do not execute.

Comment: So you don't want to delete it then? You just want to detect whether it is present? Please edit your question.

Comment: I need to be able to delete the key if it exists, because i am the one creating it.

Comment: Have you tried the calling the batch script command `reg delete` from Matlab?

Comment: @underfloor Did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine MATLAB's [winqueryreg](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/winqueryreg.html) together with a [system](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html) call.

---

An example (not tested):

```
path_top_level = 'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT'
path_low_level = 'mwsamp.mwsampctrl.2\clsid'

full_path_to_reg_key = strjoin({path_top_level,path_low_level},'\')

value = winqueryreg(path_top_level,path_low_level)
if ~isempty(value)
    system(['REG DELETE' full_path_to_reg_key])
end
```

Note that the above will delete all subkeys and values under *clsid*.
For more information, you can run:

```
REG DELETE /?
```

in Windows CMD.